# How do you ensure that async methods will run asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asynchronous

In .NET 4.0 I'm using the `FtpWebRequest` async methods.

One issue I'm running into is that I'd like a timeout option.

To achieve this I'm currently passing a `ManualResetEvent` around in the async state and then calling `ResetEvent.WaitOne(30000)` after initiating the request, ensuring the boolean response is true (or throwing a `TimeoutException`).

If my async methods run asynchronously, I believe this is fine, as they start in another thread, my current thread continues to the `WaitOne`, and then either the asynchronous methods complete or the timeout fires.

Something like this:

```
 var ar = state.Request.BeginGetResponse(
  new AsyncCallback(BeginGetResponseCallback),
  state // has a ManualResetEvent
 );

 // Won't reach here if BeginGetResponse run synchronously
 // as indicated by ar.CompletedSynchronously.
 // The risk is then that BeginGet blocks infinitely
 // without a timeout (as I'm seeing)

 if (!state.ResetEvent.WaitOne((int)5000))
   throw new TimeoutException();
```

However, if my async methods run synchronously (as indicated by `CompletedSynchronously`) then the `WaitOne` is never reached, and the thread blocks infinitely.

Is there a reliable way (perhaps a `BackgroundWorker`?) to ensure the `Begin/End` calls happen asynchronously, or alternatively a better and more reliable way to enforce a timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered simply using the [FtpWebRequest.TimeOut property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout.aspx)?

Something in the direction of:

```
          FtpWebRequest request = null;

        request.Timeout = 3000;

        Func<WebResponse> responseDelegate = () => request.GetResponse();

        var asynchRes = responseDelegate.BeginInvoke(null, null);

        try
        {
            responseDelegate.EndInvoke(asynchRes);
        }
        catch (TimeoutException e)
        { 
            // bla
        }
```

**Come to think of it, also try to specify the TimeOut and call the BeginGetResponse, it should work since it actually calls the Synchronous method behind the scenes.**

Comment: Doesn't work for asynchronous methods. `Timeout is the number of milliseconds that a synchronous request made with the GetResponse method waits for a response`

Comment: Great! You can wrap this call with a delegate and wait on its completion. Catch the TimeOutException on the EndXXX method.

Comment: I have to use the Begin/End methods for other reasons (being async isn't the issue). Let's just assume those two methods have to be called. Given that, I'm not sure how/where the TimeOutException gets thrown in your proposal? A bit of code maybe to demo your point?

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately I *have* to use `BeginGetResponse` not `GetResponse` as behind the scenes it calls some internal callbacks which I'm leveraging (even when `CompletedSynchronously`, which only indicates which Thread ran the functions, not which functions were called).

Comment: As I said, I believe it will work with BeginGetResponse as well, since it invokes the Synchronous method behind the scenes.

Comment: Looking in DotPeek that doesn't seem to be the case. I'll keep at it though thanks.